# Why does this Cypher return an array of arrays for the `data` key?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**Query**

```
curl -X POST \
  http://my-neo4j.example.com:7474/db/data/cypher \
  -H 'Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 10c0796f-d397-4c05-8f6d-9dcde4baca8a' \
  -d '{
  "query" : "MATCH (c:category) RETURN c {.categoryName} ORDER BY c.categoryName"
}'
```

**Response**

```
{
    "columns": [
        "c"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "categoryName": "Scenario"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "categoryName": "Theme"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "categoryName": "Video Mood"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

**Question:** Why doesn't the result look like *this*…

```
{
    "columns": [
        "c"
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "categoryName": "Scenario"
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Theme"
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Video Mood"
        }
    ]
}
```

❓

Comment: What tool/API are you using to generate this result?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I've updated the question to be more precise. As you can see from the url path, `db/data/cypher`, I'm using the Cypher http endpoint.

Comment: FYI this endpoint is deprecated. Instead you should  use the HTTP transactional endpoint : `/db/data/transaction/commit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The returned `data` is an array of rows.
- Each row is an array of columns (one for each item in the `RETURN` clause).
- `RETURN c {.categoryName}` returns just a single column. And, since you used a [map projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/maps/#cypher-map-projection) to specify the column value, the resulting value is a map (that contains a single field in your case).

If your query had used `RETURN c.categoryName` instead of `RETURN c {.categoryName}`, then you might of found the result to be less confusing:

```
{
    "columns": [
        "c.categoryName"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            "Scenario"
        ],
        [
            "Theme"
        ],
        [
            "Video Mood"
        ]
    ]
}
```